# Xquery How to extract the distinctive-terms from a set of xml nodes within a set of xml records?

Tags: xml, xquery, distinct, marklogic

Assume we have a set of xml records. Each record has a `<paragraph> pla pla pla </paragraph>`. How to extract the `distinctive-terms` from all paragraphs of all records? **Not** from each paragraph separately. The following code extracts  `distinctive-terms` from each paragraph separately.

```
 for $record in /rec:Record 


 for $record in /rec:Record 
 let $distinct-terms:= cts:distinctive-terms(<info>{$record/rec:paragraph } </info> ,<options xmlns="cts:distinctive-terms"><max-terms>10</max-terms></options>)//cts:text/string()
 return 
 $distinct-terms
```

The output that I want is the  `distinctive-terms` that represents all paragraphs within all records **Not** for each record  individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the loop to inside the function call:

```
cts:distinctive-terms(/rec:Record/<info>{./rec:paragraph}</info>)
```

Comment: What does the dot operator followed by a slash operator `./` in `{./rec:paragraph}` mean?

Comment: It is shorthand for the current context node. In this case `/rec:Record/` iterates through all rec:Record root elements, and `<info>{./rec:paragraph}</info>` gets evaluated for each. So basically, `.` refers to rec:Record here..

Comment: By the way: `./` can also be omitted